# How do I add an Object to a enum defined class?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to follow this code from Oracle docs that show you how to use Java ENUMS. However, I am trying to add a "Clown" in the final `protoDeck` since each deck of 52 cards can contain an additional "Clown" or "Joker" card. I cannot add the CLOWN to a SUIT or a RANK because its none of them.

I tried creating a new `enum` as

```
   public enum Clown {Clown}
```

and tried to put this inside the protoDeck but it does not work

```
    public class Card {
        public enum Rank { DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
            SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE }

        public enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES }

        private final Rank rank;
        private final Suit suit;
        private Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
            this.rank = rank;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        public Rank rank() { return rank; }
        public Suit suit() { return suit; }
        public String toString() { return rank + " of " + suit; }

        private static final List<Card> protoDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();

        // Initialize prototype deck
        static {
            for (Suit suit : Suit.values())
                for (Rank rank : Rank.values())
                    protoDeck.add(new Card(rank, suit));
        }

        public static ArrayList<Card> newDeck() {
            return new ArrayList<Card>(protoDeck); // Return copy of prototype deck
        }
    }
```

Comment: _but it does not work_ is never enough information for us to help. Say what error you got? And where exactly?

Comment: Your arrayList is declared to be of type Card. Where actually you tried to accommodate it?

Comment: I think it would be better if you add something like UNSPECIFIED to RANK and SUIT Both. And then create a new card

Comment: @KDM : Thanks a lot dude! I ended up using your logic and everything works!

Comment: @summerNight posted it as an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @KDM and @TAsk

I ended up making it work like this:

```
    public class CardSet {

        // Create ENUM for both Suites and Ranks
        public enum Ranks {TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE, CLOWN}
        public enum Suits {SPADES, HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS, CLOWN}

        private final Ranks rank;
        private final Suits suit;
        private int numOfDecks;

        public CardSet(Suits suit, Ranks rank) {
            this.rank = rank;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        private static final List<CardSet> deck  = new ArrayList<CardSet>();

        static {
            for (Suits suit : Suits.values()) {
                for (Ranks rank : Ranks.values()) {
                    if ((suit != Suits.CLOWN && rank != Ranks.CLOWN) || (suit == Suits.CLOWN && rank == Ranks.CLOWN)) {
                        deck.add(new CardSet(suit, rank));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public int getNumOfDecks(){
            return this.numOfDecks;
        }

        public List<CardSet> getNewDeck(){
            return new ArrayList<>(deck);
        }
```

And the output is something like this with CLOWN-CLOWN at the end:

```
    SPADES-TWO
    SPADES-THREE
    SPADES-FOUR
    SPADES-FIVE
    SPADES-SIX
    SPADES-SEVEN
    SPADES-EIGHT
    SPADES-NINE
    SPADES-TEN
    SPADES-JACK
    SPADES-QUEEN
    SPADES-KING
    SPADES-ACE
    HEARTS-TWO
    HEARTS-THREE
    HEARTS-FOUR
    HEARTS-FIVE
    HEARTS-SIX
    HEARTS-SEVEN
    HEARTS-EIGHT
    HEARTS-NINE
    HEARTS-TEN
    HEARTS-JACK
    HEARTS-QUEEN
    HEARTS-KING
    HEARTS-ACE
    CLUBS-TWO
    CLUBS-THREE
    CLUBS-FOUR
    CLUBS-FIVE
    CLUBS-SIX
    CLUBS-SEVEN
    CLUBS-EIGHT
    CLUBS-NINE
    CLUBS-TEN
    CLUBS-JACK
    CLUBS-QUEEN
    CLUBS-KING
    CLUBS-ACE
    DIAMONDS-TWO
    DIAMONDS-THREE
    DIAMONDS-FOUR
    DIAMONDS-FIVE
    DIAMONDS-SIX
    DIAMONDS-SEVEN
    DIAMONDS-EIGHT
    DIAMONDS-NINE
    DIAMONDS-TEN
    DIAMONDS-JACK
    DIAMONDS-QUEEN
    DIAMONDS-KING
    DIAMONDS-ACE
    CLOWN-CLOWN
```

Answer (score 2):

## Make `Card` into an interface.

You can link `Clown` together in the same group as the other cards, just make it behave appropriately in these situations too. So you'd have something like:

```
public interface Card {
  Rank getRank();
  Suit getSuit();
}
```

```
public enum Rank { DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
        SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE, OTHER }
```

```
public enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES, NONE }
```

```
public class RegularCard implements Card {
    private RegularCard(Rank rank, Suit suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() { return rank; }
    public Suit getSuit() { return suit; }
}
```

```
public enum MiscellaneousCards implements Card {
  CLOWN, JOKER;

  // etc.
}
```

Comment: Note that `enum` may implement interfaces as well, so OP may leave `Clown` as `enum`.

Comment: Might it be better to call the new `Suit` `NONE'?  This might be more appropriate.

Comment: @TagirValeev He also wanted to have Joker

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot add the CLOWN to a SUIT or a RANK because its none of them.

I am not good at card games but I just want to suggest one thing that `Clown` or `Joker` is also part of `Suite` in many games it is actively take part in game.

So my suggestion is you should not create any other `enum` but just add `Rank` or `Suite` for `Clown`.

[`Joker`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joker_(playing_card)) does have specific rank `500` or `50` in many games which mean `Joker` does have rank which you can represent by `UNDEFINED` OR `CUSTOM`.

```
public enum Rank { DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX,
                  SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE, CUSTOM }

public enum Suit { CLOWN, CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES }
```

Answer (score 1):

In most card games, the CLOWN matches ANY suite and ANY Rank. So you may just add ANY to both the Suite and Rank. Now the problem comes when you are creating protoDeck. You can add a method isValid to either Rank or Suit that returns true only when `(Suite == ANY && Rank == ANY) || (Suite != ANY && Rank != ANY)`.